react переписать handler в другом стиле
У меня есть такой код, здесь все элементарно и работает
const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState<boolean>(false);
const opendAccordionHandle = (event: SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>, expanded: boolean): void => {
    if (expanded) {
        setIsOpened(true);
    } else {
        setIsOpened(false);
    }
};

но мне нужно написать его как-то по-другому, когда мы обновляем state при помощи prevState, можете пояснить что от меня хотят?)

Смена состояния типа Boolean с использованием prevState
setIsOpened(s => !s);

Т.е. в setIsOpened передается функция колбэк, которая должна вернуть новое состояние. В функцию будет передано предыдущее состояние.
В общем виде это выглядит так:
setState( (prev) => {
// Тут какая то работа с prev
return newState;
})

У вас в коде это может быть так:
setIsOpened(s => !!expanded);

Или
setIsOpened(s => expanded ? true : false);

Только вот в явном виде предыдущее состояние в вашем примере не используется.

setIsOpened(s => !!expanded); прикольное решение, спасибо

@АлексейМелентьев Если верить описанию ваших типов, то т.к. expanded: boolean то можно просто setIsOpened(s => expanded);, нет смысла делать двойное отрицание. А так ! это простой способ получить boolean значение из пееменной

Не понимаю почему бы вообще не сделать setIsOpened(expanded)

@OliverPatterson да можно и так, но хотелось то с превстейтом )

у меня s подчеркивает ts, пишет что мы мол не используем эту переменную вообще поэтому я написал просто setIsOpened(!!expanded) хотя можно и без отрицаня да, ну посмотрим отругають меня или нет на ревью))
